# Qual a diferença entre usar inner join ou por relacionamentos no where

Tags: sql

Bom dia, estou com a seguinte dúvida, trabalho em um empresa onde o pessoal enche o saco quando o assunto é usar `inner join` por questão de eficiencia e processamento do banco de dados, gostaria de saber se o relacionamento entre tabelas feito no `where` é realmente "melhor" e o porque ja que sempre ouvi que o inner era melhor por deixar o select mais limpor e organizado.
Claro se ocorre  não é especificamente para um servidor de bd, ou se aplica a todos?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eles estão errados. A notação `inner join` foi introduzida na versão SQL92 do padrão ANSI SQL. Todos os principais bancos de dados adotam a sintaxe de junção do SQL92. Como a maioria dos servidores já estavam no mercado antes do novo padrão, eles também incluem a forma de junção antiga `where`, porém é preferível usar o novo padrão pelos seguintes motivos:

- Condições de junção e condições de filtro são separadas em duas clausulas diferentes (a subcláusula `on` e a cláusula `where`, respectivamente), tornando a consulta mais fácil de entender e manter.
- As condições de junção para cada par de tabelas estão contidas em suas próprias cláusulas `on`, tornando menos provável que parte de uma junção seja omitida por engano.
- Consultas que usam a sintaxe de junção SQL92 são portáveis entre servidores de banco de dados, ao passo que a sintaxe antiga `where` é ligeiramente diferente entre os diferentes servidores.

Como pode [ver aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause), no final da tudo no mesmo, por isso é melhor optar pelo `inner join`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, ajudou bastante!

Answer (score 3):

Em questão de resultados, não terá diferenças. Sobre desempenho, a condição de junção INNER tem um ganho discreto comparado com o WHERE, pelo fato de ser interpretado antes.

Ordem de interpretação: 1 - FROM; 2 - ON; 3 - INNER; 4 - WHERE; 5 - SELECT;

Mas existem dois fatores que fazem a utilização do INNER ser aconselhada: Padronização e flexibilidade.

O padrão ANSI 92 estabelece o uso dos operadores de junção INNERs. Com relação a flexibilidade, imagina que mude a regra de negócio de seu sistema e você precise alterar o INNER por OUTER, utilizando a clausula WHERE, isso pode gerar um pouco de dor de cabeça. Já com INNER, basta alterar algumas palavras.

Answer (score 2):

Os servidores de banco de dados oferecem recursos para você analisar a maneira como eles executarão a query. Exemplos:

- [Microsoft Sql Server Execution Plan](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178071(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [MySql EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html)
- [Oracle EXPLAIN PLAN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm)

Estes recursos mostram qual é o plano de execução de uma determinada query e ajudam a entender se algo de fato implica na performance. Em MS Sql Server, por exemplo, você vai descobrir que **o plano de execução é idêntico para INNER JOIN explícito (usando a cláusula ON) ou implícito (determinando as ligações na cláusula WHERE)**.

Antes de orientar a maneira de codificar pela performance, é importante aprender a utilizar estes recursos e conhecer de fato o comportamento do banco, de modo a não se deixar atrapalhar por mitos e quem sabe até ajudar a derrubar estes mitos.

Quantos aos prós e contras, tendo sido a performance já excluída:

- Como já citado em outra resposta: INNER JOIN explícito pode ser convertido em OUTER JOIN com menos trabalho.
- Como já citado em outra resposta: INNER JOIN explícito é padrão da indústria e portanto compatível entre os SGBDs.
- Quanto a legibilidade, isso depende da cultura do time. Teus colegas provavelmente consideram o INNER JOIN implícito mais bacana.